# "Empty" GET request using PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm down to step 5 of the OAuth flow for Mailchimp's API. [Documentation](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/oauth2/) I'm sending the right token (I've tested it in their playground) and I'm getting back invalid token errors

Here's what I've got:

```
  $headr3 = array();
$headr3[] = 'OAuth 1476f8c8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$headr3[] = 'User-Agent: oauth2-draft-v10';
$headr3[] = 'Host: login.mailchimp.com';
$headr3[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$url3 = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $headr3,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url3,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => ''
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$dec_respo = (json_decode($resp, true));
var_dump($dec_respo);
```

I'm thinking that the way I'm sending the data is incorrect, but not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: https://github.com/mailchimp/OAuth2-sample-apps/blob/master/php5/OAuth2Client.php#L239 and https://github.com/mailchimp/OAuth2-sample-apps/blob/master/php5/OAuth2Client.php#L452

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an error on my part.

I had this:

```
$headr3[] = 'OAuth 1476f8c8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

But should have had this:

```
$headr3[] = 'Authorization: OAuth 1476f8c8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```